# How to copy files automatically from Linux hadoop edge node to windows shared drive directly?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, hadoop, automation

could you please share your thoughts/processes to copy files from linux machine to windows shared folder automatically using shell script and ftp/scp options ??

I knew that we can download the  files to local windows machine from linux using winscp and filezilla , but if we wants to copy files directly to windows shared drive. 
Thanks in advance for the help .

Answer (score 1):

Mount the windows share on the Linux machine and set a cron job to copy the files if you need it automated.

If you have Ubuntu then follow this tutorial on mounting the shared drive.
 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Or if your windows has a ssh server running you can run a cron job to copy over sftp. Using this tutorial

https://askleo.com/how_can_i_automate_an_sftp_transfer_between_two_servers/